# Using MS programs in Ubuntu

Tags: windows

I like most computer users, have many Windows based programs. Can these be operated under Ubuntu and if so what is required.
Thanks for your help Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can run programs that are designed for windows with "**wine**".
Just install "wine" and then you should be able to install those programs.
I think that you can install wine by typing (in the terminal):
`sudo apt-get install wine`
and typing your password when prompted for it.

Comment: It should be noted that this will only work with **most**, not all of the Windows software. Particularly, more complicated software like games, graphics design, etc. wont work without quite a bit of effort (or not at all)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can - http://wiki.winehq.org/. Most of the windows software can run with wine.